# Нужен ли методу VK API execute access_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vkontakte-api

Приложение пишу на RoR. Задача такая, нужно забрать несколько стен сообществ одновременно. Если запрашивать по одному, то время выполнения будет очень большим, но все работает.

```
url='https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get'
uri = URI.parse(url)
parameters =  {'owner_id'=>'-00000000'}
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, parameters)
```

Однако, при использовании метода `execute`

```
url='https://api.vk.com/method/execute'
uri = URI.parse(url)
parameters =  {'code' => 'return [API.wall.get({"owner_id":-00000000})];'}
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, parameters)
```

даже при запросе одной стены выдает ошибку:

> User authorization failed: no access_token passed.

Согласно документации ни `wall.get`, ни `execute` не требуют прав доступа. Подскажите, как заставить `execute` работать?

Comment: Не вижу никаких преград. Вы делаете что-то не так. [пруф](https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=6772222)  и что это за `id` -00000000 ??

Comment: Это `id` любого сообщества ВКонтакте. Ну например: -56929213. Какой пруф нужен? Я ж говорю, первый вариант работает, но он не устраивает...

Comment: @mobilik ах, если `execute` только так говорит, то значит, конкретно для него надо авторизовываться, чтоб запрашивать методы от имени пользователя. Как авторизоваться можно смотреть [ТУТ](http://vk.com/dev/auth_sites)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Как авторизоваться вобщем-то понятно. Вопрос в том, что в документации по этому методу написано, что авторизация не нужна. Или отнестись к этому как к надписи на заборе?

Comment: У них полузаброшенная документация, поэтому половину приходится порой делать методом тыка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот метод не требует "прав доступа". Это не тоже самое что и access_token. Но, судя по всему, сам метод execute всё же требует access_token. Сам напоролся на это.

---

### UPD 2018 года:

Ответ, как и вопрос, уже потерял свою актуальность. Теперь для всех запросов необходимо передавать *access_token*.

> C **14 мая 2018** года сервисный ключ доступа обязателен для работы со всеми методами.

Подробнее можно прочитать на [странице в документации](https://vk.com/dev/service_token).

Comment: а что такое access_token? просто чтоб было? или с его помощью все таки подтверждаем право доступа? )

Comment: @nobilik да, фактически это подтверждение прав доступа. "Не требует прав доступа" в этом контексте означает, что эти права есть у любого известного ВК токена, и никаких дополнительных прав при получении токена запрашивать не надо.